# First time using .JSP; getting "JSONCore cannot be resolved to a type" (JSONCore is a local class)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Decided to use Tomcat and .JSP for one of my latest projects, and I've hit a little snag. It seems my local class "JSONCore" "cannot be resolved to a type."

Snippet of index.jsp (problem area):

```
<%
    JSONCore jsonHandler = new JSONCore();
    jsonHandler.searchSongs("search_query").getString("songID");
%>
```

Snippet of JSONCore.java:

```
import httpclient.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class JSONCore {
public JSONCore () {
    ...
}
```

```
public JSONObject searchSongs(String query) throws Exception
{
    ...
}

public String getStreamURL(String songID) throws Exception
{
    ...
}

public JSONObject callRemote(String method, String post) throws Exception
{
    ...
}
```

}

The strangest part of all is that it DOES compile and build properly into a .war from NetBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packageless classes are invisible for classes inside a package. Since JSP's are compiled into a class in a servletcontainer-specific package, the packageless `JSONCore` class is invisible for the JSP.

Put the `JSONCore` class in a package and use either the full qualified class name to declare and instantiate it, *or* use the `@page import` statement.

---

That said, the JSP is the wrong place for the job. You should be using (indirectly) a Servlet class for the job. See also [How to avoid Java code in JSP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Comment: Sounds about right, thanks BalusC. Didn't realize the web pages weren't associated with any particular package like normal programs, haha.

Comment: You're welcome. I would however warmly recommend you to take my advice of avoiding Java code in JSP files. Not only for us, but also for yourself, now and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSP import directive to let Java know where to get the implementation of your class from. JSP get translated to java and therefore follow the same rules as regular Java code.